# Leaflet zoom buttons on top of Bootstrap dropdown menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, leaflet

As shown in the screenshot below. Is this a problem with bootstrap or leaflet? How can I move/style the dropdown menu so that it's on top of everything else?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the leaflet zoom buttons have a greater `z-index` than the dropdown menu.

I'd play with increasing the z-index for the dropdown and see if it goes on top of the zoom buttons.

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly the same as [Leaflet bug #3690](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/3690): the map does not create a stacking context, and the z-index of the controls' container apply to the stacking context of the map's siblings.

You might want to use some CSS on your map container to force a [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context).