# Leaflet layer control appearing behind other div's with lower z-index

Tags: leaflet

As can be seen in the screenshot, the Leaflet layer control appears behind other div's, whereas I want it to appear in front of them.

[image]

The 'Key' and 'Participants' div’s have a z-index of 20.

Leaflet assign various z-index values to layer control div’s hierarchically structured within the map:

- `.leaflet-pane { z-index: 400; }`
- `.leaflet-top { z-index: 1000; }`
- `.leaflet-control { z-index: 800; }`

As I understand it, any one of these should make the layer control appear above the Key / Participant div’s, but they don’t.

I have tried assigning z-index values to other div’s in the Leaflet div hierarchy, to no effect.

I am using Leaflet v1.9.3.

Can anyone advise how to get the layer control to appear above those other div’s?

A live example can be seen (for a period) at https://track.trail.live/event/welcome-way-2023.

Comment: Most likely related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/41007536/4768502 - check your stacking contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @IvanSanchez, the problem was indeed the stacking context.

The Leaflet layer control is by definition within the *map* `<div>`, but the 'Key' and 'Participants' `<div>`’s are (have to be) outside the *map* `<div>`; since they have to sit above the map, they will have to sit above anything contained within the map.